# Insert to Oracle Varchar2 field from Java 2 SE using JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, quotes

I am attempting to create a simple update statement in jdbc. At this stage I don't want to used "prepared statements" but will look into that later.  That being said.  Here is the basic SQL statement I am attempting to execute:

```
update customers.clients set comments = 'V' where id_number = IDN.getText();
```

IDN is a simple jText field.

Here is what I have but I am getting errors.  I do realize that prepared statements are better but I've inherited this code and it doesn't use this approach so I want to be able to understand how to deal with ' and " and various java fields and their values.

This isn't working:
    stmt.execute("update customer.clients set comments = 'V'" + " where UPPER(r.id_number) = " + " + IDN.getText());

I guess I don't understand how to use the quotes around the literal and the call to the IDN.getText();  I would be grateful for both a working statement and an explanation of how to think about how to quote various things in this type of string.

Very grateful.

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: unclosed string literal

Comment: Changed update statement to the following:  stmt.execute("update resp.respondents set comments = " + "'V'" + " where UPPER(r.id_number) = " + " + IDN.getText());UpdateClient.java:933: ';' expected
                                stmt.execute("update customers.clients set comments = " + "'V'" + " where UPPER(r.id_number) = " + " + IDN.getText());

Comment: What is the data type of `r.id_number`?  The column name implies that it is numeric.  The fact that you are applying the `UPPER` function implies that it is a string.  The `r` alias is invalid because you have no table aliased to `r` in your query.  Does `IDN.getText()` return a string that represents a number?  Might `IDN.getText()` return a string literal that includes the single quote character?

Comment: still like to know how to quote the literal but this compiles

    String idn1 = IDN.getText();
    stmt.execute("update resp.respondents set comments = '" + idn1 + "' where UPPER(id_number) = " + IDN.getText());

Answer (score 1):

Basically, since you aren't using `PreparedStatement`s, any **value** you want to pass from the java side to the database will be a literal. If it's a string, it should be surrounded with single quotes (`'`):

```
// Note the quotes added around IDN.getText()
stmt.execute("update customer.clients" + 
             " set comments = 'V'" + 
             " where UPPER(r.id_number) = '" + IDN.getText() + "'");
```